# Can't push code into Github

Tags: git, github

Keep getting this error when trying to run 'git push':

```
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>
```

I already did this procedure, but then I get this other error:

```
fatal: 'angrails-front' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Not sure what to do from this point...

Comment: So do you have the correct access rights?

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -r` (i.e. show your remote branch). It looks like you added a remote without specifying the correct  URL.

Comment: What are the `origin` and `url` values you used in `git remote add <name> <url>`?

Comment: The origin I used was the repo name I already have on Github. The URL was the HTTP one. I just want to update my code on github by pushing from the same local repository.

Comment: How are you connecting to Github? I mean, are you using SSH or HTTPS? Or did you download the Zip file to the local machine? Also, as leo.fcx and Matt mentioned do you have the remote URL added to the git local config? Can you provide the config details of your repo. The config is located in .git/config file in your project directory. Can you copy and paste it here.

Comment: @Matt, I'm on the master branch

Comment: @Vish, I downloaded a zip file and now trying to re-push it. Also, I can't find my config file at all.

Comment: if you've downloaded the zip file then you've not setup the repo locally. You need to initialize git in the project director `git init` and then copy the git repo URL based on your connection setup HTTPS or SSH. Then use the above command to add the remove url.
`git remote add <name> <url>`

name could be anything you want to use to refer to the repository e.g I prefer `origin or upstream` and url would be the https `https://github.ibm.com/digital-xyz/projectname.git`  or ssh `git@github.com:xyz/projectname.git` url of the got repository.

Comment: You say you downloaded a zip file; but a zip file download on GitHub does not get you a (copy of the) Git repository, it gets you *one commit out of* the Git repository. In general you should use `git clone` to *clone* a Git repository, which will set everything else up. Note, however, that if you make a new clone now, it (obviously) won't have the work you just did.

Comment: @Vish, alright, I did that all but when I try finally pushing to Github I get this error:    
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
Tried Googling it for a while but nothing has worked so far...

Comment: Yes, you're getting the error because your git repository local master is not in sync with the origin repo. You probably need to make a initial commit locally. Then do `git fetch <repo name given when adding remote>` `git rebase <repo name>` rebase will fetch the upstream and then overwrite your local commit on top and create a new commit then try `git push`.

Comment: Another error when running 'git fetch': 
fatal: <repo name> does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
At the same time it does recognize it as a git repository. I'm so lost...

Comment: Try git fetch <your repo name>. Also, is this your git account you're trying to access or you trying to push to someone else's repo?

Comment: It's my git account and I'm trying to push it to my own repo on Github.

Comment: can you also paste the .git/config data to verify if the remote repository was added.

Comment: Already tried git fetch <my repo name> and got the error I've mentioned before...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173519/discussion-between-vish-and-rony-b).

Comment: And I still don't have any 'git/config' generated in my repo, even after trying all of this.

Comment: What is the url you're trying to push to?

Comment: Too late...Nothing worked. Already created a new repository on Github and pushed my code into it. Thank you all though.

Answer (score 2):

Try cloning the repo first: if that succeed, a future fetch will also succeed.
After that, modify a file, add, commit and push

```
cd /a/path
git clone https://github.com/Roeck/angrails-front
cd angrails-front
# modify a file
git add .
git commit -m "new commit"
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to start with a note first.

**Note**: If you are getting *does not appear to be a git repository* , run `git init` from your project directory.

First check if you have origin remote setup by running

```
git remote -v
```

It should show something like the following

```
origin: some_url (push)
origin: some_url (fetch)
```

If it is not showing anything like above, you have to add it manually.
Do the following

```
git remote add origin <your_origin_url>
```

In the above, `<your_origin_url>` is your project repo.
To get the project repo, simply open your project in github and copy the url.
Now try `git push` it is supposed to work. If it is not, comment below.

Comment: Hi, I've checked my origin remote working properly. It's showing both (push) and (fetch) URL's. 
But then I run "git push" and I get that same initial error again:
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>

Answer (score 0):

Finally noticed the error. I've had a subfolder with the same name and couldn't notice that until now. That's why git was getting confused. Silly, I know. Thanks everyone, though!

Comment: subfolder in your git repo?

Comment: In my local repo, before uploading it to git.

Comment: Ok. Glad you made it.